# Folium not recognizing JSON from TravelTime

Tags: python, json, folium, travel-time

I'm attempting to create a isochrone map in Jupyter Notebook/Folium, showing how far from downtown Chicago you could get in 45 minutes by car. TravelTime (TravelTime.com) has a ton of excellent APIs to do this, but I'm unable to plot them into Folium/Jupyter Notebook.

Here's a link to the [JSON produced by TravelTime](https://github.com/KevinNMcpu/mapping_project/blob/main/chicago.json).

Here's what I've tried codewise:

```
import folium
import json
m = folium.Map([41.87899134154521, -87.63554279241286], zoom_start=6.5)
with open('chicago.json', 'r') as openfile:
     json_object = json.load(openfile)
folium.GeoJson(json_object).add_to(m)
m
```

It produces a blank Folium map. No polygon showing the drivetime json. Console has an error message:

> "Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object."

The output produced by TravelTime does seem much different than other GeoJSONs I've seen on Stackoverflow and elsewhere.

I tried converting the JSON to a dict, but that didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an API output from a Python Dictionary to a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531382/converting-an-api-output-from-a-python-dictionary-to-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Anybody having the same problem as me, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531382/converting-an-api-output-from-a-python-dictionary-to-a-dataframe/71558662#71558662) by a Travel Time dev to get Travel Time to directly generate a GeoJson for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).